# Is there a better way to prune impossible labels from my segmentation probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am creating a network (based on UNet architecture) to try to learn how to segment some experimental tissue. The network performs well, but when generalizing it makes predictions that anatomically could not be next to each other. I want to incorporate this extrinsic knowledge into my network during training so it can learn to not make these mistakes.

To do this I created an adjacency matrix that defines what classes may be next to each other and I am applying it with a convolutional method. However, the training with my custom pruning layer is painfully slow. Is there a better approach? Should I even be pruning the outputs or would this be better as a loss function?

Here is the layer I have so far. It does indeed learn but very slow. I think this is because I'm doing convolutions on the CPU using scipy.signal library, then moving that data back to the gpu.

```
# Where x is the LogSoftmax output of the network
class AdjacencyPruningLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, adjacency_matrix):
        super(AdjacencyPruningLayer, self).__init__()
        self.adjacency_matrix = torch.from_numpy(adjacency_matrix).float().cuda()

    def forward(self, x):
        # normalize
        labels = torch.argmax(x, dim=1)
        deep_copy = x.clone()
        for b in range(x.shape[0]):
            connections = self.adjacency_matrix[labels[b]].cpu().numpy()
            kernel = np.ones((3, 3))
            for c in range(x.shape[1]):
                result = convolve(
                    connections[:, :, c], kernel, mode="same", method="fft"
                )
                result[result > 0] = 1
                connections[:, :, c] = result
            connections = np.moveaxis(connections, -1, 0)
            connections = torch.from_numpy(connections).float().cuda()
            deep_copy[b, connections == 0] = 1e-9

        return deep_copy
```